# How do I debug this AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'increase'?

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I was making some code to practice, but I keep getting this error:

```
File "...", line 12, in give_raise
self.increase = increase

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'increase'
```

This is my code:

```
class Employee:
    """Sort of simulates an employee."""

    def __init__(self, first, last, salary):
        """Initialize attributes."""
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.salary = salary

    def give_raise(self, increase = 5000):
        """gives raise"""
        self.increase = increase
        self.salary = self.salary + self.increase

Employee("first", "last", 30000)
Employee.give_raise(890)
print(Employee.salary)
```

Keep in mind that I am just a beginner.
Thank you for reading this. I hope you can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Ps. I use Spyder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant this:

```
some_dude = Employee("first", "last", 30000)
some_dude.give_raise(890)
print(some_dude.salary)
```

What your code is doing instead is it's calling `give_raise` *as if it was an ordinary function*, like this:

```
Employee.give_raise(self=890)
```

So, if your tear this function out of the class and just call it like `give_raise(890)`, it would have the exact same effect. Now `self` is an integer...

You can learn how classes work using [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful.